# Convert the whole date to string format

Tags: sql-server

I am working in sql query like this:

Display the STARTING_DATE in the following format – ‘The fifth day of the month of
October, 2004’.

For example,

10-5-2004 should be displayed as'The fifth day of the month of October, 2004’

Comment: add more details please where are you stuck

Comment: I want any date like 10-5-2004 in the format like above I do not get any string  function like this in mysql

Comment: you can edit your question with more details or question gets closed if no sufficient data

Answer (score -1):

Use MySQL's [DATE_FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) to format date.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2017-09-21', 'The %D day of the month of %M, %Y');
```

**Output**

> The 21st day of the month of September, 2017

Comment: You tagged your question as MySQL. There will be an equivalent function is MsSQL too.